# Apache2 on Ubuntu server SSL certificate getting overwritten

Tags: server, apache2, ssl, openssl

my webserver is `eternialogic.com`
I have an instantssl.com free 90-day license key.

Whenever I goto `eternialogic.com`, it says that the certificate is "self-signed" for `ubuntu`.

Error.log:

```
[Wed Oct 14 17:14:57.863602 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 31565] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for eternialogic.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Oct 14 17:14:57.864075 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 31565] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for eternialogic.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Oct 14 17:14:57.864182 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 31565] AH02292: Init: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)
[Wed Oct 14 17:14:57.908892 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 31567] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for eternialogic.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Oct 14 17:14:57.909307 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 31567] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for eternialogic.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Oct 14 17:14:57.909416 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 31567] AH02292: Init: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)
[Wed Oct 14 17:14:57.914767 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 31567] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.13 OpenSSL/1.0.1f mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Oct 14 17:14:57.914806 2015] [core:notice] [pid 31567] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

default-ssl.conf:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin eternialogic@gmail.com
        ServerName eternialogic.com

        DocumentRoot /var/www/

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

        #   SSL Engine Switch:
        #   Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.
        SSLEngine on
        SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
        SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM

        #   A self-signed (snakeoil) certificate can be created by installing
        #   the ssl-cert package. See
        #   /usr/share/doc/apache2/README.Debian.gz for more info.
        #   If both key and certificate are stored in the same file, only the
        #   SSLCertificateFile directive is needed.
        SSLCertificateFile  /etc/apache2/ssl/eternialogic_com.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/ssl.private.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/eternialogic_com.ca-bundle
        #SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/eternialogic_com.ca-bundle

        #   Server Certificate Chain:
        #   Point SSLCertificateChainFile at a file containing the
        #   concatenation of PEM encoded CA certificates which form the
        #   certificate chain for the server certificate. Alternatively
        #   the referenced file can be the same as SSLCertificateFile
        #   when the CA certificates are directly appended to the server
        #   certificate for convinience.


        DocumentRoot /var/www/
        <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
        </Directory>

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
        <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
            Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
            Order deny,allow
            Deny from all
            Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
        </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule> # vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

ports.conf:

```
Listen 83

<IfModule ssl_module>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>
# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Comment: Where did you get the SSL certificate from?  Did you buy an SSL certificate from a known certificate issuer or no?

Comment: @ThomasW.    instantssl.com  - They provide a free SSL option

Answer (score 0):

Let's Encrypt is the best ssl provider who offer free ssl certificates and Let's encrypt also offer automatic renewal function thus it is very easy to not only install but renew every 3 months automatically.

Instructions to install Let's Encrypt SSL

- Open SSH Terminal
- Install server dependencies `sudo apt-get update`
- Install Git `sudo apt-get install git
- Install Let's Encrypt `sudo git clone https://github.com/certbot/certbot /opt/letsencrypt`
- Go to directory `cd /opt/letsencrypt`
- Install on domain `./certbot-auto –apache -d example.com -d www.example.com`

Thats it!! 
Also you can automate the renewal task by creating the cron job
Here is the source for that
[Install SSL in Ubuntu and Automate Renewal](https://www.parthpatel.net/blog/install-free-ssl-apache-ubuntu/)`